# Ubuntu 16.04 Bluetooth headphones not recognised as headset

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

I am trying to connect my Sony WH-CH700N bluetooth headphones to my ubuntu 16.04. The device is recognised, although as unknown type instead of as headset.

I've tried installing blueman bluetooth manager, but still doesn't work.
[image]

It doesn't appear as a headset.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.